# Show image gallery

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click a picture from `galleryview`, I want to show the picture I selected from it. I did it with a toast that gives me the picture I clicked, but I want to show it in another activity.

How can I do this?

This is my gallery activity.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View vi=convertView;   
                final Players players = getItem(position);


                if(convertView==null){  


                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictures, null); 

                    ImageView image=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                    TextView text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
                    TextView text2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textNom);
                    TextView text3=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
                    TextView text4=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textDdn);

                    text1.setText(players.getNm()); 
                    text2.setText(Html.fromHtml( players.getNom()).toString());
                    text3.setText(Html.fromHtml( players.getPost()).toString().replace("Ž", "é"));
                    text4.setText(players.getDdn());

                    imageLoader.displayImage(players.getImage()image,options);


                galleryView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), players.getImage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
```

and this is what i did in other activity witch make me probleme to show it :

```
class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Players> {

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<Players> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vi=convertView;   

        Players players = getItem(position);

        if(convertView==null){  

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_player, null); 

            imageLoader.displayImage(players.getImage(), img, options);
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches for this,
I am not sure, how you have designed your data,
One simple solution,
You can set tag for all the ImageView with image url,

```
 view.setTag(url)
```

Whenever you click on imageview,  you can get the tag i.e. ImageUrl,

```
  view.getTag()
```

send url to other activity and read the bitmap and show it there in ImageView or as background as you wish.

Comment: but how can  i use it ? i parse the pictures and want to show them but still same probleme

Comment: In adapter, set the tag with url, and onItemClick retrieve the url, what does player.getImage() returns?

Comment: player.getimag return url of picture

Comment: you can use Bundle to pass data to next activity.

Comment: yes i did it and when i use putextra  give me error like this " The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Players) " evene i use the same puExttra and work in other activity :s